# Break values of one column into two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column "last_updated", with type datetime64[ns]:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'last_updated': ['11/12/14 2:44 PM','5/18/15 11:36 AM','11/12/14 
3:09 PM']})
```

I want to create two columns out of this one single column - "last_updated_date" and "last_updated_time". Also, time should be 24-hour format.

How can I accomplish this task using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast the datetime column into strings (date and time parts) after converting them into 24 hour format as shown:

```
new_cols = ['last_updated_date', 'last_updated_time']
df[new_cols] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_updated'], format='%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p')   \
                 .astype(str).str.split(expand=True)

df
```

[image]

This would retain the values as it is while exporting it to excel.

Comment: last_updated_date comes in perfect format now even one excel. For time, there is an extra random number attached, I am not sure what it is. for example: 14:44:25.970, 11:36:39.903

Comment: @Dreamer, try this: `df[new_cols] =  pd.to_datetime(df.last_updated).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').str.split(expand=True)`

Comment: @Dreamer, i think this solution is better than mine

Comment: Solutions given by both of you works well. Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
In [89]: df['last_updated_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.last_updated).dt.normalize()

In [90]: df['last_updated_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.last_updated).dt.time

In [91]: df
Out[91]:
       last_updated last_updated_date last_updated_time
0  11/12/14 2:44 PM        2014-11-12          14:44:00
1  5/18/15 11:36 AM        2015-05-18          11:36:00
2  11/12/14 3:09 PM        2014-11-12          15:09:00
```

if you want to do it faster and you are ready to sacrifice some memory, you can do it this way:

```
In [95]: df
Out[95]:
       last_updated
0  11/12/14 2:44 PM
1  5/18/15 11:36 AM
2  11/12/14 3:09 PM

In [96]: d = pd.to_datetime(df.last_updated)

In [97]: df['last_updated_date'] = d.dt.normalize()

In [98]: df['last_updated_time'] = d.dt.time

In [99]: del d

In [100]: df
Out[100]:
       last_updated last_updated_date last_updated_time
0  11/12/14 2:44 PM        2014-11-12          14:44:00
1  5/18/15 11:36 AM        2015-05-18          11:36:00
2  11/12/14 3:09 PM        2014-11-12          15:09:00
```

**UPDATE:** saving date and time columns to Excel

in order to store time properly i would convert time to string/object dtype:

```
df['last_updated_time'] = d.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

now we can save it to Excel:

```
In [133]: writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'd:/temp/a.xlsx', datetime_format='YYYY-MM-DD')

In [134]: df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

In [135]: writer.close()
```

Result (d:/temp/a.xlsx):

[image]

Comment: This works. And I can see the correct output. But when i export the result in excel using to_excel function, I get date in this format - 2014-11-12 00:00:00, and time as - 0.614189468.

Comment: @Dreamer, it's bit tricky. Please have a look [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_datetime.html)

Comment: can u help me with this as per my requirement? I am pretty new to this.